# Why would a website redirects to spam domain on some devices?

Tags: redirect, dns, github-pages, domain-name

this github [repository](https://github.com/deya-eldeen/deya-eldeen.github.io) hosts my website [www.deyaeldeen.com](http://www.deyaeldeen.com)

this is how the website should look...
[image: image1]

--

this is the spam suspendeddomain.org !!!! **(this stock photo alone should give anyone cancer)**

[image: image2]

on android devices and my mac, with main browsers, it shows normally.

on my iPhone and some other friend iPhone, the domain redirects to spam website, on another iPhone it works normally,

this is the godaddy zone and dns settings

[image: gd0]

--

[image: gd1]

--

[image: gd2]

the forward with masking forwards to deyaeldeen.com

I hope someone can help with this, on a side note, I added my domain to infinityFree service, and deactivated their account and moved to github pages, do you think this caused this problem?

this is a visual representation of ns redirects

[image: graph]

Comment: If you have moved to github pages less than 48 hours ago, I suggest you wait as DNS needs to propagate.

Comment: that was more than 2 days ago.

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess? That might cause the redirection. But I'm not sure .htaccess would distinguish between iOS versions (if versions are different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works fine now, I had to wait, it took more than two days
the documentation mentioned 48 hours though!